# Why can't I add a String to a ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

When I try to add the strings to a bytebuffer, it doesn't write in the file. While I try to add int and double it is working fine. But for strings it doesn't work.

```
buffer.asCharBuffer().put(value.getValue1());
buffer.asCharBuffer().put(value.getValue2());
```

Comment: Please add some context. What file? What is `value.getValueX()`? What is `buffer`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Then define _not working_. What do you think it should do and why? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 1):

1. Allocate a new `ByteBuffer` and set its size to a number large enough in order to avoid buffer to overflow when putting bytes to it
2. Use the `asCharBuffer()` API method so as to be able to put characters directly into the byte buffer
3. Using the `put(String)` API method we can put a String directly to the byte buffer
4. The `toString()` API method returns the string representation of the `ByteBuffer`’s contents. Do not forget to `flip()` the `ByteBuffer` since the `toString()` API method displays `ByteBuffer`’s contents from the current buffer’s position on-wards:

`UseByteBufferToStoreStrings`:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
public class UseByteBufferToStoreStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Allocate a new non-direct byte buffer with a 50 byte capacity


    // set this to a big value to avoid BufferOverflowException
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(50); 

        // Creates a view of this byte buffer as a char buffer
        CharBuffer cbuf = buf.asCharBuffer();

        // Write a string to char buffer
        cbuf.put("Your sting");

        // Flips this buffer.  The limit is set to the current position and then
        // the position is set to zero.  If the mark is defined then it is discarded
        cbuf.flip();

        String s = cbuf.toString();  // a string

        System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

[read more...](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/bytebuffer/use-bytebuffer-to-store-strings/)

Comment: You aren't addressing the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add a `String` to a ByteBuffer using the return from it's `getBytes()` method works.

```
buf.put("Your string".getBytes);
```